# What is the best way to play audio through the VScode API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Basically the title. I have tried `play-sound`, which of course does not work. I have tried creating child processes, as such:

```ts
require('child_process').exec('python music.py', (err, stdout) => {
            console.log('result', err, stdout)
      })
```

but as the CWD of debug vscode window is the actual directory of MS VS Code (created when downloading vscode), it can never find my python script. I also can't use any getCWD() methods, as again, the CWD is not where the actual source files for the extension are.

Any input helps, and I know there are extensions to play audio, this is a special use case.

Comment: If the python file is located under the extension path (packed inside the extension), you can get the extension path with `context.extensionPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with ExtensionContext.extensionPath.
ExtensionContext can usually be received as `context` at activate().
For example, for `./scripts/x.py`, you can get the path you want by

```js
vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, "scripts", "x.py").fsPath()
```

extension context doc
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext
uri doc
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri

`Note:`
If saving the mp3 to a file is not a pain for you, using the audio playback extension is the easiest option.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sukumo28.wav-preview